# how to clear data of a webview everytime the application launches?

Tags: java, android, webview

i have an application where i load url in a webview .But when i exit from the app then launches the app again it shows the same page .I want everytime the app launches it should started from the main page.How can i do this? Here is my oncreatemethod:

```
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);




    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

here is mywebclient class:

```
  public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if(url.startsWith("http://www.amazon.com/")) { 

                 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(i);
                } 

             else{

        view.loadUrl(url);

             }
            return true;




        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
```

And here is onresume():

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        web.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        web.loadUrl("http://savebigshopper.com/maybelline");

    }
```

Please help

Comment: i already use clearhistory,clearcache but nothing is happen

Answer (score 0):

The following lines of code that are above where are they located in your activity?

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);

//...

web.loadUrl("http://savebigshopper.com/maybelline");
```

My guess would be `onCreate` method. If that is the cause you should move them into the `onResume` method.

**EDIT:** really looking at it again the only code that really needs to be move to `onResume` is this line:

```
web.loadUrl("http://savebigshopper.com/maybelline");
```

**EDIT2:**

> "Everything is working fine but when i again launch the app 1st show the previous page then it shows the main page"

That would make sense to me as this will act like a web browser. You could possible hide the webview until it is done loading.

```
// add this line to your onPageFinished method inside your WebViewClient

view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Show view when page has loaded.

// inside onResume method

web.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Hide it first
web.loadUrl("http://savebigshopper.com/maybelline");
```

Comment: this code is in oncreate method.But should i remove them from oncreate?

Comment: just to test my theory move your top section of code from oncreate to on resume. Then I would create a private member for your webview inside you activity and initialize it in oncreate and call loadUrl in the onResume method.

Comment: ok so i move this line from oncreate to onresume.Everything is working fine but when i again launch the app 1st show the previous page then it shows the main page

Comment: how do i solve this problem?it shows the main page when app launches but before that it shows the previous page.

Comment: please see my edited question.Am i doing the same thing what you told me? but it is showing the same result

Comment: That was my idea... So it doesn't hide the webView then? You may have to put an image or something on top of your webView while it is loading the page. I can't think of any other way right now.

Comment: ok so instead of making the webView invisible, set it to blank before you load you page. `webView.loadUrl("about:blank")`